# Make button approval or not approval php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to make button approval or not
By php and save it on database (phpmyadmin)
Or make statues active or [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjfdp.png)not active

Answer (score 0):

create a button inside of a form in HTML like:

```
<form method="post">
<input type='button' name='approval' value='approval'>
</form>
//PHP code

if(isset($_POST('approval')))
 {
  $status='active'; 
 }
else
 {
$status='inactive'
 }
```

then using the SQL query store the value of $status variable inside a column in your database.